# Trying to change the background color of a div every second using setInterval. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I a have a list of colors in an array and I would like to make a function that goes through the array and  takes the color that is associated with the index of the array to change the background of the div every second. The color of the div should depend on where the index of the array is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var array = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

var counter = 0;
var nextColor;

function  bgchange() {
    $(".box").css("backgroundColor", "");
    counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
    nextColor = array[counter];

    $(".box").css("backgroundColor","'" + nextColor +"'");

}


    setInterval(bgchange, 1000)


});
```

I want to accomplish this task by using the code that is similar to the one above but that actually works.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WjKyj/)

Switch `backgroundColor` to `background-color`:

```
function  bgchange() {
    // $(".box").css("background-color", "");  // Unnecessary command
    counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
    nextColor = array[counter];

    $(".box").css("background-color", nextColor); // Also no need to wrap
                                                  // variables with quotes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hCKA8/.

```
<div id="box">...</div>

$(document).ready(function() {  
 setInterval(function() {
    $('#box').animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 1000)
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'green' }, 1000); 
    }, 1000);

 });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. although your using the jQuery ui and you did not go through an array it was still helpful.